# How can I extract a simple folder out of a repository?

Tags: automated-testing, ranorex

I have recorded many items with Ranorex and didn't pay attention to put them into separate repositories. So now, all items are in the same repository.

As a preparation step, I have created some folders (*Simple folder*) on top level and placed the items into those folders.

I'd now like to move each of these folders into a separate repository.

I can cut the folder in one repository and paste it in another, but doing so breaks the compilation. I wonder if there's a "refactoring" which can be applied and everything is kept working.

Comment: I do not think there is a quick fix, you will have to start from doing it one file at a time; even it means you will have to modify your own script.

Comment: Does it work to use drag'n'drop to move a folder from one repository to another while updating references? I noticed that Ranorex provides drag'n'drop where I did not expect it first; maybe here as well.